# Mysql Select Count For Every Date In Month

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table like the following:

```
date_upload|url_upload|status_upload
2017-11-01 |www.com   |verified
2017-12-01 |www.com   |verified
2017-13-01 |www.com   |verified
2017-11-01 |www.com   |verified
```

and I want result from count like this:

```
date_upload |count_upload
2017-01-01  | 0
2017-02-01  | 0
..........  | 0
2017-11-01  | 2
2017-12-01  | 1
2017-13-01  | 1
2017-14-01  | 0
..........  | 0
2017-31-01  | 0
```

The result should return a count of every date in this month, although mine records just 4.

Comment: You should do that rather in your program logic instead of SQL.

Comment: can you help me, i need array that contain that result

Comment: @Alkhawarizmi We're not a help site, we are a Q&A site. Ask a well-structured question (see [ask] for more info) and receive answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a calendar table:

```
SELECT t1.date, COUNT(t2.date_upload) AS count_upload
FROM
(
    SELECT '2017-01-01' AS date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-01-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-01-03' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '2017-01-31'
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date_upload
GROUP BY
    t1.date;
```

In practice, the subquery aliased as `t1` can be replaced with a bona fide *calendar* table containing those dates.

Comment: but i just have 1 table, whats mean t1.date and t2.dateupload.
and i must write all select from 2017-01-01 until 2017-31-01 ?

Comment: Yes. SQL is designed for getting **existing** data.

Comment: @juergen d
can you give me example for get that result. i use php.

Comment: Give it a try. If you can't get it work then ask another question with the code you got stuck with and ask a specific question about it. This is not a coding service.

Comment: @Alkhawarizmi The point which Juergen is making is that the series of dates has to come from _somewhere_.  If it is not already in your database, then the above query shows one way you can generate it.  Or, you could handle this on the PHP side.